# Why does this script only print up to 32 characters?

Tags: python, random, passwords, generator

Ok so I found a random password generator, it works amazingly but there is two things I want to know about it.
1. Why does it only print a maximum of 32 charachters and how can I get it to print more?
2. (Optional but it kinda ties in with number one) Why does it always print a number four in the middle?

Here is the code.

```
import uuid

def my_random_string(string_length=100):
    """Returns a random string of length string_length."""
    random = str(uuid.uuid4()) # Convert UUID format to a Python string.
    random = random.upper() # Make all characters uppercase.
    random = random.replace("-","") # Remove the UUID '-'.
    return random[0:string_length] # Return the random string.

while True:
    print(my_random_string(100)) # For example, D9E50C

my_random_string()
```

Comment: this is just bad code on so many levels...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a random password generator, write one of those. Don't use [UUID](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html), not only because of the length complexity (it will be in blocks of 32 chars), but because the password would only contain numbers and A-F.

You can use something along the lines of:

```
import random
import string
def passgen(n = 12):
    possible_lettters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    return ''.join(random.choice(possible_lettters ) \
                   for x in range(n))

In [92]: print(passgen(30))
cjBQgGJO5nlEyMlP2fdiZ6ra4IvDzF
```

Note that `possible_lettters` here is composed of both upper and lower case letters, making a case sensitive password. But you can of course replace `string.ascii_letters` with `string.ascii_uppercase` for a password containing only upper case characters.

Comment: To be complete, you should add `.upper()` to the end.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid had I wanted uppercase passwords, I would've chosen `string.ascii_uppercase` instead of `ascii_letters`. I chose all letters on purpose, to show that you can achieve case sensitive passwords.

Comment: The OP specifically is using `.upper()` - so you should add your comment to your answer because it explains it better.

Comment: (Sorry for being a noob, I am kinda new to python) What do I put in the print place?

Comment: @Meduza you mean `print(passgen(100))`?

Answer (score 0):

A random password generator that will generate a password with a user - defined number of characters:

```
    from random import randint
    def passwordgen(characters):
        chars = '1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM'
        password = ''
        for i in range(0, characters):
            password = password + chars[randint(0, len(chars))]
        return password
```